# Is it possible to use XML to configure HTML rendered by JSF Facelet?

Tags: html, xml, jsf

Our web application is built on JSF2 and features high degree of client configuration. Recently we had an idea to use XML to configure HTML element visibility down to the element level (using JSF2 elements' rendered attribute). Namely, we want to specify rules in XML, and these rules will return a boolean value in the runtime (through a bunch of rules checking classes) to decide whether to display an element or not. These rules should be flexible enough to check on the common variables in a web application (like request url, query strings etc). Without getting into too much detail, is this idea possible/feasible to implement? Has anyone tried to implement one?

Comment: Just try and ask here once you stumble upon a roadblock.

Comment: @BalusC will do. Thanks!